# how does shorthand operator in java works different from normal operator?

Tags: java, operators

i know that by default numbers are stored as integer in java but

```
byte x = 10;
x = x + 10;
```

is giving error while

```
byte x = 10;
x += 10;
```

is compiling fine

Comment: When you do += that's a compound statement and Compiler internally casts it. Where as in first case the compiler straight way shouted at you since it is a direct statement :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) have an answer for you

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

```
short x = 3;
x += 4.6;
```

and results in x having the value 7 because it is equivalent to:

```
short x = 3;
x = (short)(x + 4.6);
```

So in your case your second statement equlas to

```
x = (byte) x + 10;
```

That is the reason compiler is happy about.